# Three additional rows using read.table in R 3.5

Tags: r

I am currently using R 3.5. 
If I read a csv with read.table or read.csv, three additional lines are inserted. In addition, the first character of the number is not displayed in line 14. Is this a bug or a feature?

Here my example code and the results:

original csv:

```
   Timestamps            H_Accu_Cell_Temp
1  1                    0.986812468128254
2  0.986812468128254    1
3  0.986545798058286    0.976126352748508
4  0.986163754276242    0.976075120964319
5  0.986849444565436    0.976334054547901
6  0.986474103568515    0.976091900039722
7  0.988482343788316    0.980937037663843
8  0.989252408009774    0.977824034185387
9  0.988385671670406    0.978756689011549
10 0.988243992921956    0.982650133549427
11 0.988233697491554    0.977553653045176
...
```

here's my code:

```
data <- read.table(file = file.input, 
                   header = TRUE, 
                   sep = "\t", 
                   dec = ".", 
                   quote = "\n")
```

and after that I have this data in R:

```
          Timestamps        H_Accu_Cell_Temp
1   .988482343788316       0.980937037663843
2  0.989252408009774       0.977824034185387
3  0.988385671670406       0.978756689011549
4         Timestamps        H_Accu_Cell_Temp
5                  1       0.986812468128254
6  0.986812468128254                       1
7  0.986545798058286       0.976126352748508
8  0.986163754276242       0.976075120964319
9  0.986849444565436       0.976334054547901
10 0.986474103568515       0.976091900039722
11 0.988482343788316       0.980937037663843
12 0.989252408009774       0.977824034185387
13 0.988385671670406       0.978756689011549
14  .988243992921956       0.982650133549427
15 0.988233697491554       0.977553653045176
...
```

When I save the data and read in the data I just saved, I get this here:

```
write.table(data, 
            file = file.output, 
            append = FALSE, 
            quote = FALSE, 
            sep = "\t", 
            eol = "\n", 
            na = "NA", 
            dec = ".", 
            row.names = FALSE, 
            col.names = TRUE)

data <- read.table(file = file.output, 
                   header = TRUE, 
                   sep = "\t", 
                   dec = ".", 
                   quote = "\n")

          Timestamps        H_Accu_Cell_Temp
1   .986545798058286       0.976126352748508
2  0.986163754276242       0.976075120964319
3  0.986849444565436       0.976334054547901
4         Timestamps        H_Accu_Cell_Temp
5   .988482343788316       0.980937037663843
6  0.989252408009774       0.977824034185387
7  0.988385671670406       0.978756689011549
8         Timestamps H_Accu_Cell_Temp_M1_PCB
9                  1       0.986812468128254
10 0.986812468128254                       1
11 0.986545798058286       0.976126352748508
12 0.986163754276242       0.976075120964319
13 0.986849444565436       0.976334054547901
14  .986474103568515       0.976091900039722
15 0.988482343788316       0.980937037663843
16 0.989252408009774       0.977824034185387
17 0.988385671670406       0.978756689011549
18  .988243992921956       0.982650133549427
19 0.988233697491554       0.977553653045176
...
```

I tried different files as well as read.csv, but always with the same result.
Am I doing something wrong or is that really a bug? Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I tried the exact same code with the exact same file on several computers tonight. The only difference was that R 3.4.4 was installed on two computers and on the other two R 3.5.0. With R 3.4.4 it works without problems! Only with R 3.5.0 I have the problem described above. I even tried R 3.5.0 on a computer (with the same problem as above) and then uninstalled R 3.5.0 and installed R 3.4.4, then it works fine.

Here the console output with **R 3.5.0** and RStudio Version 1.1.442:

```
> file.input <-'C:/temp/Correlationmatrix.csv'
> data <- read.table(file = file.input, 
header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ".", quote = "\n")
> print(data[1:5,1:2])
Timestamps  H_Accu_Cell_Temp
1  .988482343788316 0.980937037663843
2 0.989252408009774 0.977824034185387
3 0.988385671670406 0.978756689011549
4        Timestamps  H_Accu_Cell_Temp
5                 1 0.986812468128254
>
```

Here the console output with **R 3.4.4** and RStudio Version 1.1.442:

```
> file.input <-'C:/temp/Correlationmatrix.csv'
> data <- read.table(file = file.input, 
header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ".", quote = "\n")
> print(data[1:5,1:2])
  Timestamps H_Accu_Cell_Temp
1  1.0000000        0.9868125
2  0.9868125        1.0000000
3  0.9865458        0.9761264
4  0.9861638        0.9760751
5  0.9868494        0.9763341
>
```

For the above reasons, it must have something to do with the installation of R 3.5.0 and not with my code. Does anyone have similar problems? Can somebody help me out?

Thanks

Comment: that's not a tab-separated file, just use `sep = ''` (the default)

Comment: when it csv, why dont u use `read.csv`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answers. 
It is a tab-separated file, otherwise I would get only one column. Anyway, I tried sep = ' ' as well as read.csv, I still have this problem...

Comment: well I tried it on your example and it works for me. but it's not a tab separated file, if anything it's a fixed-width file, you would have to believe that the first line has a different tab width than the other lines if you had a tsv

Comment: Thank you for trying.
I have tested the same code with the same data on the same network drive on another computer (also Windows). There it works perfectly. The only difference is that R 3.4.4 is still installed on that computer.
I'm sorry if I didn't present the results so beautifully. I copied the results from the RStudio Console and Notepad++.

Comment: I just updated my question with my attempts from tonight

Comment: I tried on another computer with r 3.5 and it still works fine. I can reproduce your errors if I use `sep = '\t'`, but like I keep saying this is not a tab-separated file. Using `sep = ''` (the default value for white-space delimited files, it works just fine

Comment: @rawr thank you very much for trying again and sorry for my late answer. We had a public holiday in Germany and so I hat a long weekend.
It is really a problem with sep "\t", but I don't understand exactly why. If I use write.table(..., sep = "\t", ...) and then read.table(..., sep = "\t", ...) I have the problem describe above. If I use the same code but omit sep = "\t" it works without problems. But then I write and read a " " sep table. How could I read in a big "\t" sep table in R 3.5.? In R3.4.4 it worked fine with read.table (..., sep = "\t", ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

The problem was in read.table(..., **quote = "\n"**, ...). If I delete quote, everything works fine with read.table(..., sep = "\t",...).

I honestly still have no idea why this makes such a difference between R3.4.4 and R3.5. But it works. Thank you all for your help, especially rawr.